# Wordpress .htaccess causing redirect loop

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been facing a problem with my WordPress app for over a month now and I couldn't make it work. I thought it was a problem with DNS server, then I thought I had a problem of caching, then a problem with the application (the wordpress redirecting it wrongly) and now I believe I have a problem with .htaccess

If you go to www.porta8080.com.br my website work fine, but when I remove the WWW it makes a redirect loop. Somehow it is not changing the URL, so it reloads the page and it's redirected again and again and again. I checked with cURL and same happens.

If I remove the .htaccess and change the permalinks settings to Query Strings it works. But anything that relies on URL rewriting (friendly URLs and stuff like that) fail.

Since I'm using OpenShift I think my conditions and rules are wrong. I'm using the default WP .htaccess and I added some things to force the WWW

This is my htaccess at the moment

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all to enforce "www" in WordPress, there is simple, non-htaccess based solution.

i.e. Keep using standard htaccess file of WordPress and for www version. Go to WordPress Settings -> General

There you have two fields for your site's url:  WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL) , make sure both urls have http://www version in it.

Then WordPress will enforce www version for all Urls of your website.

This may solve your htaccess and redirect loop issue also?

Comment: doesn't work. I get the redirect loop. if either WordPress or .htaccess try to redirect, it falls into a loop. the problem is that the protocol and domain never changes with the redirection.

Comment: Have you deleted your custom htaccess so it is only default htaccess by WordPress created?

Comment: yes, I have. redirections to the same domain are not addint http://www to the URL